# I need persistant storage of member id and email to restore an active session in a Progressive Web Apps on iOS

Tags: ios, codeigniter, local-storage, persistent, progressive-web-apps

I am researching the possibility of making a website I manage into a Progressive Web App rather then maintain a Webview wrapper app on the iTunes store. the site  works fine as a PWA, the only issue is that login information is lost and the visitor has to log back in every time the PWA is put in the background. I have found a plethora of information about offline caching, but that is not what I need. I need browser session data to remain persistant in the PWA. I looked into cookies, localStorage, and indexedDB ... all seem to get whipped out once the PWA is (paused) pushed to the background.

Answer (score 0):

[IndexDB is a persistent storage](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb) and [supported by all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=indexdb) including Safari in iOS. If you are not seeing the data persisted, then you should me missing something in the code.